# how to display an image at a specific location in LaTex?

Tags: graphics

I've imported an image but it doesn't display where I put the code.  It shows up halfway down the next blank page.  Here's the code I am using.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{sandwich theorem.PNG}
\caption{The Unit Circle \label{fig1}}
\end{figure}
```

How do I get it to display where I put the code?

Comment: This is because the `figure` environment is a float. On [tex.se] this would be a duplicate of [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and/or [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `[H]` will force it to render where you put the include. For example:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{sandwich theorem.PNG}
\caption{The Unit Circle \label{fig1}}
\end{figure}
```

A similar problem has already been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text).